# Matlab on cloud

Tags: android, matlab, cloud

Can I upload my matlab's program executable file on a cloud server such as that of an amazon or azure. The basic purpose is to send sound data from android to cloud to perform analysis. I already have the matlab program. If possible kindly suggest a method to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to do this.

1. If you have MATLAB Compiler, you can produce an executable file from your MATLAB code, and you can run that on the cloud just like any other executable. Make sure to take care about the time it takes to start up these executables, which (as the MCR needs to be started) can be long relative to the actual computation itself.
2. You can purchase a license of MATLAB Distributed Computing Server, and run those on the cloud. MathWorks have a [white paper](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/discovery/matlab-ec2.html) on how to do this for Amazon EC2 - I'm sure it's also possible on Azure, but don't know of any technical examples to give you - perhaps contact MathWorks to ask.
3. If you have a MATLAB license, you can also access MathWorks own cloud resources via [MATLAB Mobile](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/mobile/index.html) for free, including storage of up to 500MB of your own data. Perhaps this might be less convenient if you need to access your algorithm via an Android app.

Since I note that you've tagged your question with Android, I'm guessing that you have an Android app that needs to perform some sound-based algorithm, which you currently have implemented only in MATLAB. If that's case, then you may also want to consider the idea of using [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab-coder/) to convert your MATLAB algorithm into C code, which can then be incorporated directly into your Android app and run on the device rather than in the cloud. I would guess that that would be a lot more responsive than any of the cloud-based methods above.

Hop that helps!

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, Sam. I'll look into it and approach you in case of any difficulty

Answer (score 2):

Someone has made Octave (a free Matlab clone) available on the cloud:

http://octave.im/

If you have sensitive information, note that there's no guarantees what will happen to it. Also since I believe this is an individual hosting the service, there are probably no uptime/persistence guarantees.